# Cannot open a webpage refuses connection

Tags: r, rcurl, httr

I am trying to read below webpage
"http://www.thehut.com/electronics/digital-cameras/nikon-coolpix-s3100-compact-digital-camera-black-14mp-5x-optical-zoom-2.7-inch-lcd-grade-a-refurb/10641935.html"

using below code

```
  parenturl = 'http://www.thehut.com/electronics/digital-cameras/nikon-coolpix-s3100-compact-digital-camera-black-14mp-5x-optical-zoom-2.7-inch-lcd-grade-a-refurb/10641935.html'

  srcpage = getURLContent(parenturl)
  page = htmlTreeParse(parenturl,useInternalNodes = T,encoding='UTF-8')
```

but it fails with an error message 
"Error: Internal Server Error"

Not sure how to get around this.

Thanks, Savi

Comment: Try with `htmlTreeParse(getURL(parenturl))`

Comment: it just comes back with  <h1>HTTP Status 500 -</h1> but I am able to access this via browser. Do I need to set any variables ?

Comment: Try adding a `useragent = 'R'` argument to `getURL`: `getURL(parenturl, useragent='R')`.